# Can I put comments in between or after multiline properties in a Java Properties file?

Tags: java, configuration

I've got a properties configuration file with properties that have many values separated by commas.  I want to put comments next to some of them, but it seems that this is not possible?

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
property: value1,\
    value2,\
    ...
    value44,\ 
    value45,\ 
    # value45 comment
    ...
    value89,\ # another comment
    value90
```

Clarification: I'm supplying the config to a web service I don't own, so I can't use one of the extensions to the properties format like [bracket-properties](http://code.google.com/p/bracket-properties/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible as Java properties files can have only single line `# comments`.

However, you might be aware that **you can also define properties in xml format and the XML syntax will let you enter multi-line comments**.

If you decide to give XML a chance then you will need to call [**`Properties#loadFromXML(InputStream)`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML%28java.io.InputStream%29) to load your XML property file.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. A comment must appear on a line by itself, and it consists of optional white space followed by the `"#"` or `"!"` character, and then arbitrary text up to the end-of-line. You can find the full specification of Java Properties files in the Javadoc documentation for the [`load(java.io.Reader reader)` method of the `java.util.Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29) class.